# Excel Column Charts being slightly off for the same number

Tags: excel

I have an Excel Column Chart that compares numbers from the last 5 years for a presentation. These numbers are calculated and thus have like 8 decimal places. I have formatted the Data Labels on the chart to one decimal point but the bars (Being very large in the desired format) are a few pixels off because of the hundreths place numbers.

Unfortunately Imgur is blocked at my work so I can't upload a picture.

But my sample data is

```
Year       Source Data     Chart Label Shows
2011       98.28453219      98.3
2012       98.21156551      98.2
2013       98.26666667      98.3
2014       98.71048616      98.7
2015YTD    98.7376131       98.7
```

The Colums for the two `98.3` entries are slightly off and the two for `98.7` are also slightly different heights.

Is there a formmating way to 'round' the bars like I round the Labels using formmating or am I going to have to write a macro to round the source and overwrite the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a formatting way to 'round' the bars like I round the Labels using formatting

I think not.

> am I going to have to write a macro to round the source and overwrite the values

I don't see that is necessary. I just cloned your sample data from A1:C6 to A10:C15 with Paste Special Values, then (in B11 and copied down to suit):

```
=ROUND(B2,1)
```

then charted both `Source Data` and `Chart Label Shows`.

[image: SO31880010 example]

> Unfortunately Imgur is blocked at my work so I can't upload a picture

Even if not from work or as a link, I think an image might be useful (unless one or other of the charts I have shown will serve) because I am not quite certain what you are asking.